# Problem with SWR/next js (0 , swr__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_8__.useSWR) is not a function

Tags: javascript, next.js, swr

I am having an error that i can't seem to fix,

my code is as follows:

```
"use client"
import useSWR from 'swr';

const fetcher = (url) => fetch(url).then((res) => res.json());

const HebdoCirculaireContainer = ({title}) => {
    
    const {data,isLoading, error} = useSWR('https://api.kfarhbab.sscc.app/v1/website/circular?month=1',fetcher);

    console.log(data);

})
```

the error is the follow: TypeError: (0 , swr__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_8__.useSWR) is not a function

i can't seem to find the problem nor find a solution online , thanks in advance

Comment: What are you Next.js and swr versions?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem.

If you are calling your SWR hook in a component that is missing 'use client', adding that should fix it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It is expected because:

In Next.js App Router, all components are React Server Components (RSC) by default. You could only import the key serialization APIs from SWR in RSC.

It is documented here:

https://swr.vercel.app/docs/with-nextjs#rsc

```js
import { unstable_serialize } from 'swr' // ✅ Available in server components
import { unstable_serialize as infinite_unstable_serialize } from 'swr/infinite' // ✅ Available in server components
```

```js
import useSWR from 'swr' // ❌ This is not available in server components
```